# Standard python error for input being too large?

Tags: python, exception

I have an object that processes images to reduce their size (by center cropping). The object is constructed with a given size to crop down to, and then it provides a function called process() to actually crop the image. But if the image is smaller than the specified output size I need to throw an error.

Is ValueError the appropriate error here or is there a better standard error for this or should I create a custom error type?

Code:

```
class CenterCropCameraPreprocessor(object):
    """Class for adding preprocessing images by center cropping them.
    """

    def __init__(self, center_size):
        self.center_size = center_size

    def process(self, color_img):
        if color_img.shape[0] < self.center_size[0] or color_img.shape[1] < self.center_size[1]:
            # THROW ERROR
            
        # DO WORK
```

Comment: `ValueError` seems reasonable to me. It doesn't really matter too much, unless your `except` statements will need to distinguish this error from other `ValueError`s.

Comment: What exceptions are thrown by your imaging library?  Maybe that would be a good place to start.

Comment: @MarkRansom I think that the issue here is that the library does *not* throw an exception; this is a condition added by the application itself.

Comment: @MarkRansom I'm not aware of any library functions for center cropping. My understanding that in python/numpy/opencv the standard is to use slicing to do a crop. And so I think I would get an IndexError if I tried to do the the slice without checking the dimensions first. ValueError seems more appropriate than IndexError I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is essentially a ValueError: your application says that any value less than the expected dimension is an exceptional processing error.  Just as a float sqrt routine rejects negative inputs, you are rejecting inputs too small for your function.

Use the same exception they do: `ValueError`.

---

An alternate possibility is to create your own exception value, which the users will then need to explicitly catch.  Especially if your package will throw other exceptions, this is a useful way to distinguish *your* exceptions from those of the Python run-time system and standard packages.  See any tutorial on Exceptions for how to create your own ... but note that it incurs a little overhead for you, and a little for your users.